# Show url in a div after click the href on angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I was searching on Google, but i can't find the answer.
I want to show the url in a div after the url has been clicked using $http (dynamic links).

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter:search as results" ><a ng-href="{{getSrc(file._name)}}" target="_blank">{{file._name}}</a></li> 
    <div>
            **SHOW URL OF CLICKED LINK HERE**
    </div>
  </ul>

   $scope.read = function(){
    var request = $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'request.php', 
    });
    request.then(function(response){
        $scope.files = response.data;
    }, function(error){ 
        alert(error.data);
    });
}

$scope.getSrc = function(src) { 
    return 'files/' + src;
};
```

Tried everything but i cannot make it work. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could put an ng-click on the link to a function you define on the scope and pass in the link address to it. Then set that to a scope variable and inside your div show that scope variable. At first it won't show because you'll init it to null, but once you click the link it'll call the ng-click function passing in the link name and you set the variable and now it'll show.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter:search as results" ><a ng-href="{{getSrc(file._name)}}" target="_blank" ng-click="linkClicked(file._name)">{{file._name}}</a></li> 
    <div>
            {{clickedLink}}

    </div>
  </ul>

$scope.clickedLink = null;

$scope.linkClicked  = function(link){
   $scope.clickedLink = link;
}
```

Comment: Just a fiddle to add [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL7vzbw2/) you have a typo on the line `$scope.linkClicked(link){
` which should be `$scope.linkClicked = function(link){
`, I think!

Comment: @NarenMurali Yep, thanks. My bad as I've changed to using classes for controllers so mixed the style :). Thanks for edit.

Comment: @user441521 No problem, nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying:

```
$scope.result;
$scope.getSrc = function(src) {
  $scope.result = 'files/' + src;
  return $scope.result;
};
```

and then the html:

```
<div>
  {{result}}
</div>
```

Comment: He wanted it to show only after it's been clicked. We've got the same idea with it though.

Comment: Sure, tried that, because the {{result}} returns the last element of the array. I want to display only the clicked element, and change when click another one.